# How to extract a .gz zipfile using Python?

Tags: python, download, gzip, extract, unzip

How to extract a .gz zipefile using Python?

Example file: `http://www.o-bible.com/download/kjv.gz` (download first for script to work)

My code works, but I thing there is a better way. Suggestions welcome!

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    with gzip.open('kjv.gz', 'rb') as ip:
        with io.TextIOWrapper(ip, encoding='utf-8') as decoder:
            file.write(decoder.read())
    ip.close()
file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with` construct are generally use so you do not have to close resources yourself, so this part of code:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    with gzip.open('kjv.gz', 'rb') as ip:
        with io.TextIOWrapper(ip, encoding='utf-8') as decoder:
            file.write(decoder.read())
```

is sufficient, you might also elect to avoid nesting using ability to provide [with-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) with multiple `,`-sheared `with_item`s i.e.:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file, gzip.open('kjv.gz', 'rb') as ip, io.TextIOWrapper(ip, encoding='utf-8') as decoder:
    file.write(decoder.read())
```

Though this result in long line, so feel free to use either more short lines or longer line but less nesting.

[gzip.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open) does, in text mode, wrapping in `io.TextIOWrapper` for you so your code can be simplified to:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file, gzip.open('kjv.gz', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as ip:
    file.write(ip.read())
```

keep in mind that above requires python 3.3 or newer to work.